# What is the most memorized law?

Tags: united-states, statistics

Which codified law, excluding religious commands, has been memorized word-for-word by the most people? The only ones I have memorized are Constitutional amendments.

"Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free excersize thereof, or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press, or the right of the people peaceably to assemble and to petition the government for a redress of grievances."

"A well-regulated militia being necessary to the security of a free state, the right of the people to keep and bear arms shall not be infringed."

"The trial of all crimes shall be by jury..."

"Neither slavery nor involuntary servitude shall exist within the United States, except as a punishment for crime..."

"Congress shall have the power to lay and collect taxes on incomes, from whatever source derived..." (definitely the most popular law)

And if you count Supreme Court cases, "Roe and Casey are overruled" and "The Constitution does not confer a right to abortion."

I wouldn't be surprised if the most memorized law is the First Amendment?

Comment: Would the TV Miranda Warning (“You have the right to remain silent,” etc.) count?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the answer is going to be the Ten Commandments, or some individual commandment.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of religious law.

Comment: @user48157 While clearly the Ten Commandments are originally from the Bible, in the core they are (mostly) still valid to the day. And so if children learn them by heart, they still learn about good or evil.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is going to be that most people know that the following things are legal wrongs (see generally H.L.A. Hart, *The Concept of Law*; he describes these as near universal rules, where law and morals coincide):

- inflicting bodily harm
- killing without justification
- theft

Comment: I was thinking of actual codified laws, memorized word for word.